# When is "being a linear algebraic $k$-group" preserved?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over a field $k$, with Char$(k)=0$.

> What "group-theoretical operations" preserve the property of "being a $k$-linear algebraic group"? For example
>
> 1. When is a subgroup of a linear algebraic $k$-group again a linear algebraic $k$-group?
> 2. Are extensions of linear algebraic $k$-groups again linear algebraic $k$-groups?
> 3. If $A,B$ are linear algebraic $k$-groups and $A/B$ exists, is it a linear algebraic $k$-group?

Any other useful "operation" which preserves the property of "being a linear algebraic $k$-group" is much appreciated.

EDIT1: since I seem to have confused a lot of people, I should clarify that whenever I say "subgroup", "group-theoretic", etc, what I mean is "algebraic subgroup", "in the category of algebraic groups", etc.

EDIT2: Also, I should stress that what I'm interested in is whether the resulting thing (e.g. algebraic subgroup, quotient, extension, etc) is still defined *over $k$*, and not over some extension $K/k$.

Comment: At least if you assume that $k$ is algebraically closed, the answer to all your questions is yes, even if the characteristic of $k$ is positive

Comment: @spin what if $k$ is not algebraically closed?

Comment: Hmm. If $k$ has characteristic zero, you get for example $\Bbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of the linear group of matrices of the form $\pmatrix{1&x\cr0&1\cr}$. But is $\Bbb{Z}$ a linear algebraic group? I don't think so (if dimension as an algebraic variety were zero, then it would be finite et cetera). If you include "subvariety" into the definition of a "subgroup", then this example becomes invalid. So...

Comment: The question is ill-posed and is thus senseless. "To be a linear algebraic $k$-group" is not a group property, because an algebraic $k$-group is a more subtle object than just a group plus some extra thing.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Maybe I should have clarified that "subgroup" is meant to stand for "algebraic subgroup". I'm working in the category of algebraic groups, not of just groups.

Comment: @YCor What I meant is to consider "to be a linear algebraic $k$-group" as a property of *algebraic* groups, not just groups.

Comment: But still it's not precise. As the property "to be a group", for a set, is meaningless. A precise property would be as follows: first you probably want to fix a larger field of definition (e.g., an algebraically closed extension $K$ of $k$). Then for linear algebraic $K$-groups, you can define "to be definable over $k$", which makes sense. Probably it's not, in general, stable under subgroups, quotients, and extensions. Or you ask whether you can define subgroups, quotients, extensions in the category of linear algebraic $k$-groups (with only $k$-defined morphisms) and this is different.

Comment: @YCor I'm not sure how to explain precisely what I mean, so I'll give you some examples: I know, for example, that if $G$ is a lin alg $k$-group and $H$ is a closed normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/H$ exists and is a lin alg $k$-group (this is from SGA3); so I say "taking quotients by closed normal subgroups preserves the property of being a lin alg $k$-group". I was wondering for what "operations", like the one above, the property is preserved. I hope this helps to understand what I'm asking! :)

Comment: Good. That makes for a more interesting question!

Comment: [This answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function#Special_values) is related.